# Title page text organizing problem

Tags: spacing, titles

I have pretty newbie question. I renewed the `\titlepage` command and it works pretty well, beside one detail - the space between the last row of text (the line and 'Lublin 2013' in this case) lies too high and I can't understand why. I'd like this text to be rather on the bottom of the page.

Here is a screenshot and my `\titlepage` code:

[image]

```
\newcommand{\linia}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4mm}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{\begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
    \textsc{
    \Large
    Katolicki Uniwersytet Lubelski Jana Pawła II \\
    \linia \\
    \normalsize
    Wydział Matematyki, Informatyki i Architektury Krajobrazu \\
    Kierunek Informatyka \\
    Studia stacjonarne I stopnia } \\
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \@author \\
    \linia \\
    \LARGE{\@title} \\
    \vspace*{4cm}
    \small{Praca licencjacka napisana na seminarium \\
    \textbf{Zastosowania grafiki komputerowej}\\
    pod kierunkiem dr. Rafała Stęgierskiego} \\
    \vspace{\stretch{4}}
    \linia \\
    \textbf{Lublin 2013}

        \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the last line really down to the bottom, you need to put a `\vfill` (which adds a vertical space from 0 to infinity - hence it will drag everything coming after it to the bottom of the page), e.g.

```
...
\vfill
\linia \\
\textbf{Lublin 2013}
...
```

Now, you only have to adjust the print space of your titlepage. Here, i recommand the `geometry` package. This allows you to establish new print space settings for several pages, and then reset them, to get to your original one. In this case, you want to have the last line to be down on the page, so you have to provide a "small" bottom margin for your first page. I chose 1.5cm, but feel free to change it, in order to get your desired design. The whole thing looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\linia}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4mm}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\newgeometry{bottom=1.5cm,noheadfoot}
\begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
    \textsc{
    \Large
    Katolicki Uniwersytet Lubelski Jana Pawła II \\
    \linia \\
    \normalsize
    Wydział Matematyki, Informatyki i Architektury Krajobrazu \\
    Kierunek Informatyka \\
    Studia stacjonarne I stopnia } \\
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \@author \\
    \linia \\
    \LARGE{\@title} \\
    \vspace*{4cm}
    \small{Praca licencjacka napisana na seminarium \\
    \textbf{Zastosowania grafiki komputerowej}\\
    pod kierunkiem dr. Rafała Stęgierskiego} \\
    \vfill
    \linia \\
    \textbf{Lublin 2013}

        \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
}
\makeatletter

\title{A \LaTeX\ Article}
\author{Anna Oleksiuk}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```